# Determine the stability of the solution $x=0$ of the equation $mx''(t)+bx'(t)+qx'(t-r)+kx(t)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, delay-differential-equations

**The Problem**

> Discuss the stability of the solution $x(t)=0$ of the equation $$mx''(t)+bx'(t)+qx'(t-r)+kx(t)=0$$
>   where $m>0,b\geq 0,q\geq 0,$ and $k\geq 0$ are all constants, by constructing an appropriate lyapunov functional.

*Why I need help*

I am having difficulty constructing an appropriate lyapunov functional needed to determine the stability as I do not have much experience with delayed differential equations.

I am also not sure that my overall approach is correct as I have not see a problem of this type (a delay differential equation of order 2) before.

Also note that lyapunov functionals, are similar but different to lyapunov functions.

**My Work on the problem (so far):**

First we use lyapunov functionals to determine stability (rather than use them to determine instability)as this will allow the determination of asymptomatic stability if $x=0$ is stable. If $x=0$ is not stable, then it is unstable.

In an attempt to make the problem simpler we rewrite the equation to eliminate the second derivative:
let $y(t)=x'(t)$  then 
\begin{align}
y'(t)=x''(t)&=-\frac{b}{m}x'(t)-\frac{q}{m}x'(t-r)-\frac{k}{m}x(t)\\
&=-\frac{b}{m}y(t)-\frac{q}{m}y(t-r)-\frac{k}{m}x(t)
\end{align}
thus we get the following system
\begin{cases} 
x'(t)=y(t) \\
y'(t)=-\frac{1}{m}(b y(t)+q y(t-r)+k x(t))
\end{cases}

Here is my attempt at a appropriate lyapunov functional:
$$V(x(t),y(t))=\frac{1}{2}y(t)^2+\frac{1}{2}x(t)^2 $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've only got it for $b=q$ but I think you can adapt it and what follows is the way the answer should go. I'll make it clear where I use this and what I think might work to fix it. This should still be pretty helpful.

As a rule of thumb, integral terms are good for delay terms.

For some constants, $C_1,C_2,C_3>0$, suppose 
$$
V(\phi,\psi) = C_1\phi^2(t) + C_2\psi^2(t) + \frac{C_3}{m}\int_{-r}^0\psi^2(t+\theta)d\theta.
$$
Clearly, $V\geq 0$. Now,
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}V(x(t),y(t))&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}V(x(t),y(t))\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}V(x(t),y(t))\frac{dy}{dt}.
\end{align*}
First term:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}V(x(t),y(t))\frac{dx}{dt}&= 2C_1x(t)x'(t) = 2C_1x(t)y(t)
\end{align*}
Second term:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{d y}V(x(t),y(t))\frac{dy}{dt}&= 2C_2y(t)\frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{C_3}{m}\frac{d}{d t}\left[\int_{-r+t}^ty^2(\theta)d\theta\right],\\
&= 2C_2y(t)\frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{C_3}{m}\frac{d}{d t}\left[\int_{0}^ty^2(\theta)d\theta-\int^{-r+t}_0y^2(\theta)d\theta\right],\\
&= 2C_2y(t)\frac{dy}{dt} + C_3\left[y^2(t)-y^2(t-r)\right],\\
&= 2C_2y(t)(-by(t)-qy(t-r)-kx(t)) + C_3\left[y^2(t)-y^2(t-r)\right],\\
\end{align*}
Putting this together and choosing $C_1=kC_2$ to cancel the cross term gives the quadratic form

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}V(t) &=(C_3-2bC_2)y^2(t)-2qC_2y(t)y(t-r)-C_3y^2(t-r),\\
&=\begin{bmatrix} y(t) & y(t-r)\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
C_3-2bC_2 & -qC_2\\
-qC_2 & -C_3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
y(t)\\
y(t-r)
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}
This matrix has determinant $-(C^2_3-2\frac{b}{q}qC_2C_3+q^2C_2^2)=-(C_3-qC_2)^2$ This is where I use $b=q$, can't factor it nicely otherwise. Now, choose $C_3,C_2$ such that $C_3-2bC_2<0$ and this matrix is negative definite, so the quadratic form $\frac{d}{dt}V$ is negative definite and hence decreasing along trajectories.

Okay, so how to fix the b=q problem? I think setting $C_1=kC_2$ was the wrong thing to do, I think you want to keep the $x$ term and end up with a 3x3 matrix. I don't think you'll be able to get it negative definite, but you should be able to get it negative semi-definite because there is no $x^2$ term. It might be that the $b\neq q$ is only neutrally stable for the right initial condition, could be worth hunting for that as part of your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just a few small things. What is the 3x3 matrix system If $C_1 \not=k C_2$? How can we test if the trivial solution is asymptotically stable(If we assume the matrix is negative definite)?

Comment: Also what happened to the factor $\frac{1}{m}$ in line 3 of finding the second term?

Comment: The matrix will have the 2x2 in the top left and off diagonal terms corresponding to the x(t)y(t) term.

If the matrix is negative definite, we have asymptotic stability. If the matrix is negative definite then the quadratic form $(\frac{d}{dt}V)$ is negative everywhere. So we have $V$ decreasing along trajectories.

If the matrix is negative semi definite, we also allow for $\frac{d}{dt}V$ to be zero somewhere outside equilibrium, this allows for a solution which oscillates around the equilibrium, but does not necessitate it's existence. I suspect this is the scenario we are in.

Comment: Oh yeah, I moved the $1/m$ factor around a bit when I was writing this, that's definitely an error. If you push through the calculation with that corrected you might get something a little different. If I get the chance I will fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will award you the bounty when then $\frac{1}{m}$ error is corrected.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm not going to correct the constant, but you should be able to carry it through yourself. If that isn't satisfactory, good luck finding a better answer.

Comment: Please note that $\dot V$ is only negative semi-definite, as we can take $y \equiv 0$ and $x \neq 0$ and get $\dot V = 0$. So, you haven't proven asymptotic stability. You may be able to prove it combining your result with LaSalle invariance theorem, but I'm not absolutely sure you can use it for a delayed system such as yours.

Comment: I see what you mean, It's a good point. I think we can fix it by noticing $y=x'$ so $y=0\implies x=c$ is constant. Subbing back into the original equation we get $kc=0$, so for $k\geq0$ we have $c=0$. If $k$ was 0, the problem would only include derivatives of $x$.